# How to get full cookies data from an Android WebView?

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I have an Android app that uses a WebView.

I'm trying to get all cookies with all of their data including their "path" data, "max-age", "hostOnly" flag and "secure" flags (like in Google Chrome's [chrome.cookies.getAll()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-getAll) extension API).

[CookieManager.getCookie()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#getCookie(java.lang.String)) only returns name and value pairs of the cookies.

Any idea of how can I extract all the "raw data" of the cookies?

Comment: Did you find any solutions ?

Comment: I also run into this problem!